# Calculando valores em coluna

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Estou com uma duvida em como calcular valores que estão em coluna, consegui calcular os valores em linha, porém, em colunas não estou conseguindo, a necessidade é para criar subtotais de cada coluna que tenho se alguem tiver alguma ideia ou algum exemplo de como fazer isso agradeço.

```
  <table  class="table table-striped" height="100%">
            <thead>


                <tr>

                    <th width="170px" class="fileName alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">Date Event</label></th>
                    <th width="170px" class="fileName alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">Event Type</label></th>
                    <th width="150px"  class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;RE1A</label></th>
                    <th width="150px" class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;RE2A</label></th>
                    <th width="150px" class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;RE3A</label></th>
                    <th width="150px" class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;RE4A</label></th>
                    <th width="150px" class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;RE5A</label></th>
                    <th width="150px" class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;RE6A</label></th>
                    <th width="150px" class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;RE7A</label></th>
                    <th width="150px" class="alignCenter"><label class="titLabel">&nbsp;Total Event</label></th>
                </tr>


            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr id="no-results" ng-hide="{{noResults}}" ng-show="{{!noResults}}">
               </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="output in result">
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.referenceDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.eventType}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.re1A}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.re2A}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.re3A}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.re4A}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.re5A}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.re6A}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.re7A}}</label></td>
                    <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;</label></td>

                </tr>
                  <tr  class="primary">
                  <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>Total RE</label></td>
                  <td width="170px" class="alignCenter"><label>&nbsp;{{output.eventType}}</label></td>
                  </tr> 

            </tbody>


        </table>
```

lembrando que preciso somar os valores dos RE'S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só precisa criar uma função que totalize e então chamá-la no seu template:

```
$scope.totalizar = function(){
  var total = 0.0;

  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.result.length; i++){
    var output = $scope.result[i];
    total += (output.re1A + output.re2A + output.re3A + output.re4A + output.re5A + output.re6A + output.re7A);
  }

  return total;
}
```

E a chamada no template:

```
<label>{{totalizar()}}</label>
```

Comment: Entendi mas como eu faria para somar todos os valore do Re1A por exemplo, digo todos os valores que estao nessa coluna ?

Comment: Ué, é só colocar a variável que você quer somar na função. Dá uma olhada no código da função e adapte para o atributo que você quiser. No exemplo eu somo todos, mas se você quer somar só um é só tirar as outras